# Passing a pickled object in Django's HttpRequest

Tags: python, django, pickle

I'm currently attempting to move an sklearn model object from server side to client side. I'm new to django so I'm struggling mightily.

Option one is to jsonify all the model parameters, pass them through and reconstruct a fresh model object with those parameters.

However, in my attempts to both simplify, and learn a bit about django, I've been trying to pass a pickled object and failing.

I originally tried something simple like:

```
result = pickle.dumps({'test':'test'}, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
return HttpResponse(pkl)
```

When I got it from the front end API, if I did a simple

```
pickle.loads(api_res)
```

I get a type instance error. When I do:

```
pickle.loads(api_res.read())
```

It gives me an EOF error.

I know there's the potential to also just pickle.dump instead of the string version, but I'm having trouble with djangos content-type etc. I just seem to get gibberish on the way out.

The unfortunate icing on the cake is that, it's apparently difficult to find instances of people serializing objects and returning them with django, because almost all the results are about serializing/pickling the django objects themselves.

Any help/links would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Point Zero: do not ever ever ever let anyone a possibility to inject in your `pickle.load`. See [Arbitrary code execution with Python pickles](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~s/musings/pickle/).

In case you are completely sure you want to do this, check what your front-end is doing. Maybe, it alters data somehow or sends the data in a field. Also, check `api_res` instance's class docs.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions as to how to pass a sklearn model object from server side to client side? That's ultimately what I'm trying to do. We train our models server side, but currently have no way for our developers to access them client side in a notebook for various data sciencing.

Comment: I'd say JSON or CBOR is a good option. You need to unpickle an object than serialize it in an architecture independent manner.
However, I doubt it is the best way to integrate it with Notebook.